# Get table row to center in mandrill email

Tags: html, css, email, inline, mailchimp

I am trying to get the below  tags to be centered however they keep appearing on the left. This is for an email template hence the inline styles.

```
 <tr align="center" style="display:inline-block;">
                         <td style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; border-right: dotted 1px #9B989E; padding:5px;">*|SECTION|*</td>
                         <td style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; border-right: dotted 1px #9B989E; padding:5px;"> *|ROW|*</td>
                         <td style="font-size: 18px; font-weight:bold; padding:5px;">*|SEAT|*</td>
                       </tr>
```

Comment: tr is child of table and table takes : margin:auto very well for horizontal centering. have you tried that ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mcxLd

Comment: that seems to center the entire table in the middle of the email, its the text within the table row I want centered within the table

Comment: text-align:center then :) is there any width given anywhere, cause without the whole picture, it could be anything else

Comment: text-align within the row or each td?

Comment: whatever, td will inherit text-align value from parents. for vertical-align , the rule is to be for td . td {vertical-align:middle;} , usually this is the defaut behavior